# Can the expression appearing in Selberg's orthonormality conjecture be viewed as an inner product of class functions?

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, l-functions

Selberg's orthonormality conjecture states that if $F$ and $G$ are primitive functions of the Selberg class, then one has:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{p\leq x}\dfrac{a_{p}(F)\overline{a_{p}(G)}}{p}}=\delta_{FG}\log\log x+O(1)$

Where $\delta_{FG}=1$ if and only $F=G$ and $\delta_{FG}=0$ otherwise.

On the other hand, the orthogonality theorems for characters of a finite group $G$ states that:

$\displaystyle{\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{1}(g)\overline{\chi_{1}(g)}}=\mid G\mid$

while

$\displaystyle{\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{1}\overline{\chi_{2}(g)}}=0$

where $\chi_{1}$ and $\chi_{2}$ are the characters of two inequivalent irreducible linear representations of $G$.

So my question is: can $\dfrac{a_{p}}{\sqrt{p}}$ be interpreted as a character of a linear representation of a finite group of order $\log\log x+O(1)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you could possibly expect to interpret $a_p/\sqrt{p}$ -- a number -- as a character of some finite group. Not to mention that asking that a finite group be of order $\log\log x+O(1)$ is completely meaningless. Being $O(1)$ is a property of a function, not a number (the order of the group).

Is there any reason for this other than that both results/conjectures contain the word "orthogonality"/"orthonormality" in their names? That should hardly be surprising; orthonormality appears everywhere. One result says that irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis of the space of class functions. Selberg's conjecture says (something like) that primitive L-functions form an orthogonal basis of the Selberg class.

Would you expect, say, for there to be a link between the orthogonality of irreducible characters and the fact that there is an orthogonal basis of some given Hilbert space?

Comment: No, I expect all numbers $\dfrac{a_{p}}{\sqrt{p}}$ to be values of characters of some representation of a group $G$. As $\log\log x$ is seldom an integer, the perhaps faulty $O(1)$ is just the quantity $\mid G\mid-\log\log x$. One could imagine the representation of $G$ to be induced from the one of a larger group. As an example, if I'm not mistaken, an Artin representation of $Gal(L/Q)$ induces an Artin representation of $Gal(K/Q)$ where $K$ is an intermediate extension between $Q$ and $L$.

Comment: Well, sure. For each value, pick a group admitting a character with that value, and take the product of those groups. The correct way to associate a Galois rep to every place is to believe in Langlands reciprocity. If the Selberg class is the class of automorphic L-fns, then for each place there should exist a motive with L-factor the same as that of the automorphic L-fn. Add in enough hypotheses, eg that your L-fn is algebraic at infty, de Rham at a fixed auxillary prime ,etc (whatever the state of the art is these days) and that motivic L-fn should arise from a Galois rep.